# Spring Data JPA 3 auditing @CreatedDate of java.time.OffsetDateTime does not get populated

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, java-time

I am trying to add Spring Data JPA auditing in my application, specifically using `@CreatedDate` and `@LastModifiedDate` annotations. This is a Spring Boot 3 application. Using postgresql testcontainers for testing. The entity classes are created automatically using Openapi generator. OpenAPI generator creates the attribute of date-time with the type of java.time.OffsetDateTime. I have setup my entity classes with `@CreatedDate` and `@@LastModifiedDate` annotations, but I get error in my test. The test code is as follow:

```
@Test
public void shouldNotUpdateANewGatewayPcWithAllNull() throws Exception {
    // Arrange
    GatewayPcDetail updateGatewayPc = new GatewayPcDetail(
                    null, null, null);

    // Can manually create JWT
    Jwt jwtManual = Jwt.withTokenValue("token")
                    .header("alg", "none")
                    .claim("sub", "test1")
                    .claim("scope", "read:gatewaypcs")
                    .claim("scope", Arrays.asList("read:gatewaypcs", "write:gatewaypcs"))
                    .build();

    // Act and Assert
    MvcResult updateResult = mockMvc.perform(put("/api/v4/gatewaypcs/101")
                    .with(jwt().jwt(jwtManual))
                    .with(csrf())
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(updateGatewayPc)))
                    .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
                    .andReturn();

    DocumentContext documentContext = JsonPath.parse(updateResult.getResponse().getContentAsString());
    JSONArray read = documentContext.read("$[*]");
    assertThat(read.size()).isEqualTo(2);

    JSONArray names = documentContext.read("$..field");
    assertThat(names).containsExactlyInAnyOrder("name", "timezoneId");
}
```

The error I get is as follow:

```
Test shouldCreateANewGatewayPCWithNullLocationName() FAILED (1.2s)

  jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Invalid date type class com.hht.extope.restella.generated.model.GatewayPc for member class GatewayPc {
      id: null
      name: gatewayPcName
      locationName: null
      timezoneId: 0
      createdAt: null
      updatedAt: null
  }; Supported types are [java.util.Date, java.lang.Long, long]
      at app//com.hht.extope.restella.controller.gatewaypc.GatewayPcControllerTest.shouldCreateANewGatewayPCWithNullLocationName(GatewayPcControllerTest.java:626)
  Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Invalid date type class com.hht.extope.restella.generated.model.GatewayPc for member class GatewayPc {
      id: null
      name: gatewayPcName
      locationName: null
      timezoneId: 0
      createdAt: null
      updatedAt: null
  }; Supported types are [java.util.Date, java.lang.Long, long]
      at app//com.hht.extope.restella.controller.gatewaypc.GatewayPcControllerTest.shouldCreateANewGatewayPCWithNullLocationName(GatewayPcControllerTest.java:626)
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid date type class com.hht.extope.restella.generated.model.GatewayPc for member class GatewayPc {
      id: null
      name: gatewayPcName
      locationName: null
      timezoneId: 0
      createdAt: null
      updatedAt: null
  }; Supported types are [java.util.Date, java.lang.Long, long]
      at com.hht.extope.restella.controller.gatewaypc.GatewayPcControllerTest.shouldCreateANewGatewayPCWithNullLocationName(GatewayPcControllerTest.java:626)
```

From error, I assure that `@CreatedDate` and `@@LastModifiedDate` does not support types other than [java.util.Date, java.lang.Long, long]. In Spring Data JPA document, it says that it support [JDK8 date and time types](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#auditing.annotations:%7E:text=can%20be%20used%20on%20properties%20of%20type%20JDK8%20date%20and%20time%20types).

**Now my question is: How do I use Spring Data JPA `@CreatedDate` and `@@LastModifiedDate` with `java.time.OffsetDateTime`?**

For reference:
*Controller*:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v4/gatewaypcs")
public class GatewayPcController {
    private GatewayPcRepository gatewayPcRepository;

    // Constructor injection to inject the GatewayPcRepository.
    public GatewayPcController(GatewayPcRepository gatewayPcRepository) {
        this.gatewayPcRepository = gatewayPcRepository;
    }
    @PostMapping
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('SCOPE_write:gatewaypcs')")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> postGatewayPc(@RequestBody GatewayPc newGatewayPcRequest, UriComponentsBuilder ubc) {
        GatewayPc newGatewayPc = new GatewayPc();
        newGatewayPc.name(newGatewayPcRequest.getName())
                .locationName(newGatewayPcRequest.getLocationName())
                .timezoneId(newGatewayPcRequest.getTimezoneId());

        GatewayPc savedGatewayPc = gatewayPcRepository.save(newGatewayPc);
        // Build resource URI for the identifier of the new GatewayPC.
        URI locationOfNewGatewayPc = ubc
                .path("/api/v4/gatewaypcs/{id}")
                .buildAndExpand(savedGatewayPc.getId())
                .toUri();

        return ResponseEntity.created(locationOfNewGatewayPc).build();
    }
}
```

*Generated entity class*:

```
@lombok.AllArgsConstructor
@lombok.NoArgsConstructor

@Schema(name = "GatewayPc", description = "Information about an gatewayPC. G/W PC情報")
@Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2023-07-19T01:48:20.223480244Z[Etc/UTC]")
@jakarta.persistence.Entity
@jakarta.persistence.Table(name = "master_gatewaypc")
@jakarta.persistence.EntityListeners(org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class GatewayPc {

  @JsonProperty("id")
  @jakarta.persistence.Id
@jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue(strategy=jakarta.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @JsonProperty("name")
  private String name;

  @JsonProperty("locationName")
  private String locationName;

  @JsonProperty("timezoneId")
  private Integer timezoneId;

  @JsonProperty("createdAt")
  @jakarta.persistence.Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
@org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate
  @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
  private OffsetDateTime createdAt;

  @JsonProperty("updatedAt")
  @jakarta.persistence.Column(nullable = false)
@org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate
  @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
  private OffsetDateTime updatedAt;
...(redacted)
```

*Entity repository*:

```
public interface GatewayPcRepository extends JpaRepository<GatewayPc, Long>,
                                             QuerydslPredicateExecutor<GatewayPc>,
                                             QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QGatewayPc> { 

  @Override
  default void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QGatewayPc gatewayPc) {
    bindings.bind(String.class)
      .first((StringPath path, String value) -> path.containsIgnoreCase(value));
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, perhaps you have different date and time patterns in the database settings and in the application, which is why an error occurs?

Comment: The error is not in SQL, from the error I can see the exception is thrown by spring data, not something like jdbc driver.

Comment: Hi @MirzaPrangon, did you find the workaround ?

Comment: I [opened an issue in spring data](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/3074). Apparently, spring data does not support `OffsetDateTime` for auditing out of the box. For that reason, we moved to using hibernate auditing annotation, `@CreationTimestamp` and `@UpdateTimestamp`.